# Integrate a sign function wrt probability measure

Tags: probability-theory

I have to integrate the function $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\operatorname{sign}(x-a)-\operatorname{sign}(x-b) d\mu(x)$. where the sign function is given by: $\operatorname{sign}(\theta)= 1, 0, -1$ if $\theta>0$,$\theta=0$ or $\theta <0$.

Can anyone tell me how to figure this out.

thanks.

Comment: is this the measure you chose: $d\mu(x)=dx$?

Comment: Yes, that the measure I choose.

Comment: make cases : a < b and a > b, and plot the function

Comment: Subdivide $\mathbb R$ into a few sets, determined by whether $x<a, x=a, x>a$ and by whether $x<b, x=b, x>b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We choose the case $a>b$. The other cases are similar. The integral of the function $f(x,a,b):=\operatorname{sign}(x-a)-\operatorname{sign}(x-b)$  is equal to
$$\int_\mathbb R f(x,a,b)dx=\int_{-\infty}^a f(x,a,b)dx+\int_{a}^b f(x,a,b)dx+
\int_{b}^\infty f(x,a,b)dx.  $$

Then
$$f(x,a,b)=-1-(-1)=0,~~x\in(-\infty,a), $$
$$f(x,a,b)=1-(-1)=2,~~x\in(a,b), $$
$$f(x,a,b)=1-(+1)=0,~~x\in(b,\infty). $$

In summary
$$\int_\mathbb R f(x,a,b)dx=0+2(b-a)+0=2(b-a). $$